# Necessary files in Next.js build

Tags: build, web-deployment, next.js

I wrote a Next.js app and I'm close to deploying. I would like to know what are the strictly necessary files to copy on the server to deploy while keeping it SSR (not statically generated with `next export`):

- just the `.next/` folder?
- node modules as well?
- any source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy `.next` folder with `package.json` && `npm install --production` should install only the dependencies of your app.

**Keep the folder structure**.

Side note, it is bad practice to copy `node_modules` between environments cause there are some packages that are os specific.

Comment: You may need to add *.config.js files from the project root or some strange behaviours can happen, in my experience.